# Publish to play store cordova-crosswalk apks?

Tags: android, cordova, app-store, crosswalk-runtime

I already have an app on Google Play Store.
When I was using cordova 4.0 I created 2 apks: `AppName.arm.apk` and `AppName.x86.apk` and published them to play store.

So at this moment I have 2 projects with 2 different `config.xml` files:

- `<widget id="com.AppName.arm" version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">`
- `<widget id="com.AppName.x86" version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">`

Yesterday I switched to cordova v5.0.0 and I'm using the `cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview` plugin (https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview).

It creates 2 apks:

- `/path/to/hello/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/hello-x86-debug.apk`
- `/path/to/hello/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/hello-armv7-debug.apk`

both have the same ID:

`<widget id="com.AppName" version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">`

My question is: how can I publish them to play store in order to keep the old apk IDs so people can just update the app on their phones, with no need to remove the old ones and install a different app (with a different ID)?

Thanks

Comment: I think that you need to build twice and change the id each time.. the first time you uploaded the app was a misake cause you should upload both apk to the same app with same id and google will know to serve each apk to correct device(arm and x86)